# Permissions on Mac OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, permissions

I think that this is a permissions issue but I am not sure and I am not sure how to repair the problem.

I have a new MacBook.  I have 2 external drives that were previously used on another MacBook.  I have a lot of folders and XCode projects on the external drives.  When I try to work on the projects, there is a message similar to this:

"This file is not writable.  You may not be able to save your changes, but you will be able to Save a Copy somewhere else.  Do you want to edit this file anyway?"

If I make changes and try to close the project I get this error:

"The project and user files project.pbxproj and macbook.pbxuser for project “thirdtry.xcodeproj” are not writeable and cannot be saved. Your changes will be lost if you close the project. You may need to SCM edit these files to gain writability."

I have tried just to rename the folder but that permission is not allowed either unless I individually change permissions for every file in an XCode project.  As you can imagine, this could be time consuming for tons of files and projects.

I can copy the project into internal memory and can run it then after renaming the folder that contains all of the files.  This defeats the purpose of having all of the projects on an external drive.

Also, in XCode, there is no "Build and Run" there is only "Build and Debug" now.  I don't know if this is related or not.

Suggestions for how to repair **all** permissions to *all* files and folders on my external drives?  What about the "Build and Debug" and no "Build and Run" choice?

Thanks,
Linda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *Get Info* on the external drive in the Finder and check "Ignore ownership on this volume". This will let you continue to use the drive on your other computer as before. If you no longer use the old machine, Paul's answer is a better solution.

Comment: I don't see this option in Snow Leopard (I remember seeing it in older versions of Mac OS X though) - I'm not sure if this is because the option is no longer available (or moved/hidden), or because I'm not an admin user ?

Comment: It's there (although grayed out until you click the padlock and authenticate as an admin) -- but only if the selected item is an HFS+ volume other than the one you're booted from.  Make sure you have the volume icon selected, not a file/folder on it.  And make sure the Sharing & Permissions section of the Get Info window is expanded.

Answer (score 1):

The files and folders on the external drives probably have the wrong *owner*. You can easily rectify this via the command line using `chown`, e.g.

```
$ sudo chown -R myusername /Volumes/ExternalVolume/MyProjects/*
```

For documentation see:

[$ man chown](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/chown.8.html)

Comment: Changing ownership requires root access, so you must use `sudo chown ...`